# How to return a variable from a remote PowerShell session to a local PowerShell session

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that creates a new PowerShell session.  I need to return one of the variables from the myriad of variables that is created in this session to the local / calling session.  Here is my PowerShell script:

```
param
(
[string]$user,
[string]$password
)

$secure_password = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $user, $secure_password

$new_session = New-PSSession -Credential $cred

$script = {
$var1 = 0
$var2 = a
}

Invoke-Command -Session $new_session -ScriptBlock $script

Write-Host ($var2)
```

When the script executes `Write-Host ($var2)`, it doesn't print any value for $var2.  How can I return $var2 to the local session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
param
(
[string]$user,
[string]$password
)

$secure_password = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $user, $secure_password

$new_session = New-PSSession -Credential $cred

$script = {
    $var1 = 0
    $var2 = a
    $var2
}

$varFromSession = Invoke-Command -Session $new_session -ScriptBlock $script

Write-Host $varFromSession
```

Just return the variable from the session's scriptblock, either with `Write-Output` or `return` or just use the variable in another command as I've demonstrated. The return value of `Invoke-Command` will be whatever the scriptblock wrote to the pipeline.