# powershell - send the email outside the the if statement

Tags: powershell

This script will loop through a list of remote computers and check if a specific process is running under java. If it's not running it will send an email notification.

```
foreach ($server in $serverslist) {
    # checking connection to remote computer by requesting the hostname
    if ((Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { hostname }) -like '*SRV*' ) {
        # do something if connection to server is established
        Write-Host checking if process is running under java
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
            if ((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "name ='javaw.exe'").CommandLine -like '*pn9*') {
                Write-Host process is running
            }
            else {
                # do something if process is not running
                Write-Host sending email to $Using:to
                Send-MailMessage -From $Using:from -To $Using:to -Subject "process alert" -Body "process is not running on server $Using:server." -SmtpServer $Using:smtp -Credential $Using:smtpcred -UseSsl -Port 587
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        # do something if connection to server failed
        Write-Host cannot communicate with $server - sending email to $Using:to
        Send-MailMessage -From $from -To $to -Subject "communication issue" -Body "we were unable to communicate with $server" -SmtpServer $smtp -Credential $smtpcred -UseSsl -Port 587
    }
}
```

The problem is that none of the remote computers have internet access, so they can't send an email. So I need a way to tell the computer that's running this script to send the email, because it has internet access.

I realize the issue is the way the script is written. I'm already in the if statement so I run the email command from there.

How can I tell the computer running the script to send the email?
Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107333/how-to-return-a-variable-from-a-remote-powershell-session-to-a-local-powershell , just return a variable from the session and based on that variable you can decide to send an email or not